# Get value of a Binding

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to create `@State` variable inside a custom initialiser based on a binding that is passed in.  I am getting error `Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Color>' to expected argument type 'Color'`. Is there a way to extract raw value of the biding itself? This is an example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var color = Color.red
    
    var body: some View {
        
        SomeView(color: $color)
    }
}

struct SomeView: View {
    
    @Binding var color: Color
    @State var someOtherColor: Color
    
    init(color: Binding<Color>) {
        
        _color = color
        
        _someOtherColor = State(initialValue: color) // ERROR: Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Color>' to expected argument type 'Color'
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `wrappedValue` property of `Binding` to access its underlying value.

```
_someOtherColor = State(initialValue: color.wrappedValue)
```